# Unable to Identify all the <tr> when web scraping a table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to extract the data from this table:
https://hosted.mediahack.co.za/bhekisisa-vaccination-table/ using beautifulSoup.
But for some reason, my script can't identify all the "tr" elements. Also, the section where I try to extract the date produces a string 'on {{data}}'.

```
import bs4
import requests
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen  as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

myURL = 'https://hosted.mediahack.co.za/bhekisisa-vaccination-table/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36' }

response = requests.get(myURL, headers=headers)

page = urllib.request.Request(myURL,headers=headers) 

uClient = uReq(page)

#grabing the page 
page_html = uClient.read()

#close the conection 
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

page_soup

table = page_soup.findAll("table")
table[0]
temp = table[0].findAll("div", {"class":"header-title"})
table_title = temp[0].text

temp1 = table[0].findAll("div", {"class":"header-subhead"})
Date = temp1[0].text

tr = table[0].findAll("tr")

l_colnames = tr[1].findAll("th")
l_colnames[0].text

colnames = []
for i in range(0,len(l_colnames)):
    colnames.append(l_colnames[i].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Data in table is dynamic generated so you can go to chrome developer
   mode under Network tab go to xhr tab and reload you website so,
2. Where links will be appear in which data is contain in [json](https://api.mediahack.co.za/adh/mhc-vaccine-table-json.php) format
   as you click on headers URL will be there you can call that URL to
   extract data from it
   import requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}
res = requests.get("https://api.mediahack.co.za/adh/mhc-vaccine-table-json.php",headers=headers)
main_data=res.json()

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(main_data)
df.iloc[:,1:11]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate the help.

Comment: if answer help to resolve your question you can upvote or accept as answer!